# ipv6 rule priority duplication

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6

When I add ipv4 policy rules using `ip rule add` the resultant rules get added to the end of the policy table with decrementing priority from 32767

eg:

```
# ip rule add lookup 8
# ip rule add lookup 9

0:     from all lookup local
32764: from all lookup 9
32765: from all lookup 8
32766: from all lookup main
32767: from all lookup default
```

But when I use the same command for ipv6 `ip -6 rule` I get priority duplication.

eg:

```
# ip -6 rule add lookup 8
# ip -6 rule add lookup 9

0:     from all lookup local
16383: from all lookup 8
16383: from all lookup 9
32766: from all lookup main
```

16383 is 32766/2. But I don't understand why the behaviour is different and why there is priority duplication. I am using Fedora 21. Version of iproute is: iproute-3.16.0-3.fc21.x86_64.

Is this the intended behaviour for ipv6 policy routing using iproute2?
Can anyone else confirm this behaviour on other systems?